# Миграция на Linux с переносом Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code

Всем привет! Наконец-то собираюсь мигрировать на Linux (минт или убунту) с Винды. Имеется: настроенный и удобный Visual Studio Code. Хочется его взять и безболезненно как он есть перенести целиком на новую систему. Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вашу задачу поможет решить расширение Settings Sync в Vscode.
Нужно включить синхронизацию настроек, выбрать какие именно настройки нужно синхронизировать, войти в уз Microsoft или Github. Настройки будут синхронизироваться в фоновом режиме. При входе с другого компьютера в Vscode нужно будет выбрать пункт заменить локальные или
объединить вручную.

Answer (score 0):

у vscode есть несколько вариантов синхронизации, в связи с тем, что МС встроила в оригинальный пакет телеметрию и в оригинальном пакете не всем нравятся условия лицензии, пересобрали варианты без нее типа vscodium, синкается через Settings Sync, если же использовать оригинальный пакет типа visual-studio-code-bin, то в нем все настройки и плагины автоматом подтягиваются, если залогиниться через учетку МС или гитхаба, который нынче тоже принадлежит МС.

кроме того, vscode встроен как рабочий редактор на гитхабе и если зайти в любую репу и нажать на клаве на точку в любой раскладке, то можно прям в облаке кодить.
если брать локальные настройки, то у моей версии редактора на линухе они хранятся по адресу /home/user/.config/Code/User/settings.json

[ман по настройкам](https://youtu.be/e15PvHRHB_w?t=442)

ссылки для ознакомления

https://github.dev/github/dev

https://vscode.dev/